# ¿Por qué no se ejecuta el método de mi clase Game?

Tags: c++, linux, poo, sfml

He estado haciendo un **motor** de **videojuegos** con la librería gráfica **SFML** pero he querido darle un enfoque **Orientado a Objetos** por lo que hice una clase **"Game"** la cual va a ser la responsable de almacenar todos los métodos necesarios para que funcione el motor.

El método **"Initialize()"** de mi clase **"Game"** no se está ejecutando cuando lo llamo en mi código, este es mi código.

main.cpp :

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include "./Game.h"


int main(){

    Game *game = new Game();

    game->Initialize();

    while(game->IsRunning()){
        game->ProcessInput();
        game->Update();
        game->Render();
    }

    game->Destroy();

    return 0;
}
```

Game.cpp :

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "./Game.h"


Game::Game(){
    isRunning = false;
}

Game::~Game(){
}


void Game::Initialize(){
    //Window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,600), "SFML");
    printf("Initializing");

    isRunning = true;

}

bool Game::IsRunning(){
    return this -> isRunning;
}


void Game::Load(){
    //Sprites
    sf::Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromFile("../assets/hola.jpg");
    sf::Sprite sprite(texture);

}

void Game::ProcessInput(){
    sf::Event event;

    while(window.pollEvent(event)){
         if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
            //printf("Close");
            window.close();
         }      
    }

}

void Game::Update(){
    //printf("Updating");
}

void Game::Render(){
    window.clear();
    window.draw(sprite);
    window.display();
}

void Game::Destroy(){
    //printf("Close");
    window.close();
}
```

Game.h :

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

class Game{
    private:
    bool isRunning;

    sf::RenderWindow window;
    sf::Sprite sprite;

    public:
    Game();
    ~Game();
    bool IsRunning();
    void Initialize();
    void Load();
    void ProcessInput();
    void Update();
    void Render();
    void Destroy();

};

#endif
```

Con el código actual no se crea ninguna ventana, ni si quiera se imprime en consola **"Initializing"**. Por lo que veo, entiendo que no se está ejecutando el método, pero no entiendo porque no está ejecutándose si los otros métodos si se están ejecutando.

Answer (score 0):

No he usado nunca SFML, pero tu código tiene un par de cosas ... *raras*:

En tu archivo `game.cpp`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

No deberías usar I/O de C en un programa C++. Usa `#include <iostream>`.

Seguimos:

```
void Game::Initialize(){
  //Window
  sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,600), "SFML");
  printf("Initializing");

  isRunning = true;
}
```

Ahí **estás creando una variable nueva** (`window`), de alcance automático. Esa variable **es destruida** en cuanto abandonas la función.

Deberías hacer

```
void Game::Initialize(){
  //Window
  window = sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800,600), "SFML");
  std::cout << "Initializing";

  isRunning = true;
}
```

Comment: No conozco SFML ... así que es posible que no soporte la asignación de `RenderWindow`, con lo que habrá que usar punteros o inicializarla en el constructor ...

Comment: ¿Y cómo declaro esa variable "window"? cuando compilo me dice: error: ‘window’ was not declared in this scop

Comment: Pues, según el código que has puesto, la tienes ya declarada en `Game`, en tu archivo `Game.h`.